# Lissajous figure in Direct3D

Tags: c++, c++11, directx, direct3d, direct3d11

I made a cube in DirectX, but now I want the cube to move around. I want this cube to move around in a Lissajous pattern. But for some reason no matter what variables I enter my cube just makes circles instead of the Lissajous figure.

I'm not familiar with this function and I've been searching for answers but I can't seem to fix my problem. So may be I made a mistake in the function, or maybe I'm doing everything completely wrong.

This is the code I use to calculate the position, where m_Angle changes every frame so the cube keeps moving.

```
    float scale = 3.f;
    float valueA = 1.0f;
    float valueB = 2.0f;
    float valueX = scale * valueA * sin(m_Angle + ((valueB - 1) / valueB)*(XM_PIDIV2));
    float valueZ = scale * valueB * sin(m_Angle);
    m_pColoredCube_1->SetPos(XMFLOAT3(valueX, 0.0f, valueZ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liassajous figures are just an interference of different oscillations. An oscillation can be described as:

```
y(t) = amplitude * sin(2 * PI * frequency * t + phase)
```

In your case, `t` is `m_Angle`.

You then set different oscillations for the `x` and `z` component (and possibly for the `y` component, too). If you set both frequencies equal (as you did), you get a circle or ellipse, depending on the phase. What you want to do instead is:

```
float frequencyRatio = ...;
float phaseDifference = ...;
float valueX = scale * sin(m_Angle * frequencyRatio + phaseDifference);
float valueZ = scale * sin(m_Angle);
```

If you set `frequencyRatio = 2.0f` and `phaseDifference = 0`, you get the following figure:

[image: Lissajous 2:1]

Or for `frequencyRatio = 5.0f / 4.0f` and `phaseDifference = 0`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, one more question though, if you change the phaseDifference, what exactly in the graph will be changing? Or is that the range  of the x-axis?

Comment: The phase results in a kind of rotation of the figure. I.e. if you have a frequency ratio of 1 and a phase difference of Pi/2, you get a circle. If you increase the phase difference, the circle transforms to a diagonal line (as if you would look at the circle from the side where it's flat). Just [try it out](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ParametricPlot%5B%7BSin%5B2*Pi+*+3t+%2B+Pi%2F2%5D%2CSin%5B2+*+Pi+*+t%5D%7D%2C%7Bt%2C0%2C1%7D%5D).

Comment: That explains exactly why in some attempts to make the figure it just went from left to right